# how to change state value in class component, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

```
    class ContactUs extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          attach: "Attach a file (Max. 5 MB).",
        };
    }
  render() {
        function a(event) {
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
           const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        if (event.target.files[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
          // Here you can ask your users to load correct file
          this.setState({ attach: "so big file!!!" });
          event.target.value = "";
        }
      }
    }
    return ( <div>
                     <input
                      type="file"
                      accept="image/*,.xls,.xlsx,.docx,.pdf"
                      id={Styles["file"]}
                      onChange={a}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <label className={Styles["attached-file-text"]}>
                    Attach a file (Max. 5 MB).
                    {this.attach}
                  </label>
     </div>
    export default ContactUs;
```

What I want  see is when I choose >5MB file it should show "file is too big!!!" instead of " "Attach a file (Max. 5 MB)."
I try this code:  this.setState({ attach: "so big file!!!" }); , but it not working, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You need to move your function outside of the render method
2. You need to bind your method to `this` in the constructor to ensure that you can call `this.setState()` inside your method
3. You need to reference `this.state.attach` in your render method rather than `this.attach`

```
class ContactUs extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      attach: "Attach a file (Max. 5 MB).",
    };

    // 2
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  // 1
  handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;;
      if (event.target.files[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
        this.setState({ attach: "so big file!!!" });
        event.target.value = "";
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*,.xls,.xlsx,.docx,.pdf"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <label>
          {this.state.attach} // 3
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.for this you need to **move a function outside of the render function** & inside the class.
refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

2.whenever you are calling function then you need to call function with like this
**this.changeFileHandler**

Refer this for event hanndling:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

3.Also if you want to this in normal function then you need to .bind(this) to the function in constructor or at the time of calling function .

refer this for how to bind() to function:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-best-way-to-bind-event-handlers-in-react-282db2cf1530/

4.If not you don't want to attach bind function then use ES6 arrow functions

5.**always call your state with this.state.attach & not this.attach**

6.**always give function name or variable name relevant to what are you doing.**

```
     class ContactUs extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
              attach: "Attach a file (Max. 5 MB).",
            };
        }
        
            changeFileHandler = event => {
          if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
               const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            if (event.target.files[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
              // Here you can ask your users to load correct file
              this.setState({ attach: "so big file!!!" });
              event.target.value = "";
            }
          }
        }
        
      render() {
        
        return ( <div>
                         <input
                          type="file"
                          accept="image/*,.xls,.xlsx,.docx,.pdf"
                          id={Styles["file"]}
                          onChange={this.changeFileHandler}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <label className={Styles["attached-file-text"]}>
                        Attach a file (Max. 5 MB).
                        {this.state.attach}
                      </label>
         </div>
        export default ContactUs;
```